# Make a back to previous url link in error 404

Tags: html, redirect

I have many pages on my website with some 404 errors because some pages are down under construction. How can i add something to my 404.html page to redirect the user back to the page they came from before they come to visit the 404.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user back automatically, just use the `history.back()` method, but instead make it a script that runs `onload`:

```
<body onload="history.back()"></body>
```

You should probably only run this function after a couple of seconds though, otherwise the reader would have no idea what happened to them, and they'll just keep trying that link. To make the function run after 5 seconds, change your onload to:

```
setTimeout('history.back()', 1000*5)
```

the multiplication by 1000 is to change seconds to milliseconds (`setTimeout` works with milliseconds only).

Comment: @user3233575 I'm sorry about that. I tested it and found out what was the problem. This code does work. ([view edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21358281/revisions))

Comment: so its setTimeout('history.back()', 1000*5)

Comment: Yes exactly. It previously gave an error because it didn't have the single quotes and the `()`.

Comment: Yea i was wondering why i didnt work when i tested it. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript. Check this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

```
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>

<body>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What if i dont want a button to go back, How can i add the amount of seconds before i go back to the last url

Comment: Create timer with setTimeout function

Answer (score 0):

Is this question about adding a back button, or about adding something to the 404 error page?
If it's the latter this may be a solution if you are using apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache